# How to use external js script and css for custom dialog box

Tags: javascript

Could someone help me. Because I'm just started learning JavaScript.

I'm using a custom prompt dialog, before it's working when I use XMLHttpRequest
But, I want to use "Fetch" instead because it's the new one and better.

with using Fetch the dialog is not showing and I'm getting error "layer is not defined"

Here's my little question, How I can call it properly the layer.js and layer.css from the response?
I'm calling it like this (this is a message dialog):

```
layer.open({
        title: "<strong>" + formTitle + "</strong>",
        content: "<strong>" + msg + "</strong>",
        maxWidth: 500,
    });
```

Here's my code.

```
!function () {
    try {
        if (typeof (eval(layer)) == "function") { }
    } catch (e) {
        
        var css = 'https://cdn.bootcss.com/layer/3.0.1/skin/default/layer.css';
        var js = 'https://cdn.bootcss.com/layer/3.0.1/layer.min.js';

        var a = document.createElement("style");
        a.type = "text/css";
        DownloadStringAsync(css).then(_css => a.innerText = _css);
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(a)

        var a = document.createElement("script");
        DownloadStringAsync(js).then(_js => a.text = _js);
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(a)
    }

    var url = amp.mediaProxy.facade.config.media.originalSrc;
    var title = ampl_title;
    
    var formTitle = "Url Parser v1.0";
    var msg = `${title}<br>${GetTitle()}<br>`;

  
    try {
        var fileName = `TEST.txt`;
        SaveToFileAsync(url, fileName);
    } catch (err) {
        layer.open({
            title: "Error",
            content: err.message
        });
    }
     layer.open({
        title: "<strong>" + formTitle + "</strong>",
        content: "<strong>" + msg + "</strong>",
        maxWidth: 500,
    });
          
    async function DownloadStringAsync(url) {
        let response = await fetch(url, {
            method: "GET",
            cache: "no-cache",
        });
        let data = await response.text()
        return data;
    }

    function SaveToFileAsync(url, filename) {
        fetch(url, {
            method: "GET",
            cache: "no-cache",
        }).then(async function (t) {
            const b = await t.blob();
            var a = document.createElement("a");
            a.href = URL.createObjectURL(b);
            a.setAttribute("download", filename);
            a.click();
        });
    }

    function GetTitle() {
        return document.getElementsByClassName("hero-image-rating eps-line")[0].innerText + "\n";
    }
}();
```